# Delphi - ADVFN Login Problems

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

Using Delphi 10.3 with Indy Im trying to log into ADVFN.  I have setup an account with ADVFN, and have tracked network traffic with Firefox Debugger etc.

Ive tried multiple IdHTTP examples, but still no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Im trying to get a list of top gainers, and populate the memo with the returned raw html code.

```
// get cookies first...
IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';

LString := IdHTTP1.Get('https://uk.advfn.com');


// now submit the webform...
Params := TStringList.Create;
try
  Params.Add('redirect_url=aHR0cHM6Ly91ay5hZHZmbi5jb20=');
  Params.Add('site=uk');
  Params.Add('login_username=MYUSERNAME');
  Params.Add('login_password=MYPASSWORD');

  IdHTTP1.Post('https://uk.advfn.com', Params);

  LString := IdHTTP1.Get('https://uk.advfn.com/insights/toplist/london/percentage-gainer/price');

  Memo1.Lines.Text := LString;
finally
  Params.Free;
end;
```

Comment: How in the world do you expect us to be able to help you based on the miniscule amount of information you've provided? You've vaguely described an issue, provided zero details, not a single line of source code, a vague *still no success*, and not asked any sort of specific question related to your code. At the very least, there should be a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. We can't debug code we cannot see.

Comment: Please add to your q what your IdHTTP1.Get *does* return, if anything.

Comment: IdHTTP1.Get just returns the main ADVFN page.  It does not seem to login correctly.  This 'Get' should return a list of 30 stocks

Answer (score 0):

### You are `POST`'ing your login request to the wrong URL.

The HTML webform located on `https://uk.advfn.com` that you are trying to submit actually posts to `https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure`, not to `https://uk.advfn.com` like you have coded:

```html
<form action="https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure" id="login_form" name="login_form" method="POST" target="">
```

```pascal
IdHTTP1.Post('https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure', Params);
```

Also, there is a 5th `<input>` field in that webform that you are not submitting:

```html
<input  class="button"  tabindex="3" type="submit"   value="Log In" id="login_submit">
```

```pascal
Params.Add('login_submit=Log In');
```

When submitting a webform, you MUST submit every *non-empty* `<input>` value, per the HTML specifications.

Lastly, when submitting a webform for web-based authentication, the only way to know if the login was successful is to analyze the response HTML to see if it contains what you are expecting.  Unlike HTTP-based authentication, there are no special response codes you can look for in HTML-based authentication.  You should make sure your login is actually successful before you then send your `GET` request for `https://uk.advfn.com/insights/toplist/london/percentage-gainer/price`.